# Kepler.gl - issues with Dropbox when I run it locally for development

Tags: gis, kepler.gl

I am trying to install and run kepler.gl locally on ubuntu 20.04, following the dev instructions.

I have tried both the 2.3.1 tag as well as trunk, but so far have hit the same problem on both.

I do the checkout, run yarn, export the mapbox key I have and run npm start

It starts fine, I can view my data, but if i try to share / export the map url via dropbox, nothing happens (and I can see in the browser console logs that the Dropbox Client ID is not set).

What is that? Where do I get the ID from? Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It seems that we probably have to do some kind of integration with dropbox (to create a new app for dropbox) to get it working, but we couldn't figure out how...